# MSVC 2010 and UTF8

Tags: c++, sqlite, utf-8

ALL,

I'm using MSVC 2010 for my project and the latest code for SQLite.

According to SQLite documentation the query strings should be encoded as UTF-8.

As suggested from some other threads here, I tried to use u8"" prefix.

However, I got an error that "u8" is not recognized: 'u8': undeclared identifier

So, now 2 questions:

1. Is u8 C++11 only?
2. How do I make my project recognize u8 prefix?

Thank you.

Comment: Not sure where you got the idea that SQLite requires UTF-8. All the functions I've ever seen in the SQLite C API that take string parameters also have a UTF-16 version.

Comment: @MrEricSir, If I have some Unicode character inside the table name my query string will better be encoded as UTF-8.

Comment: What do you mean by "better be encoded as UTF-8"? There's no difference in terms of what characters can be encoded in UTF-16 vs UTF-8.

Comment: @MrEricSir, what I mean is that in case the table name or field name is Unicode, the query string should be UTF-8 encoded according to SQLite.

Answer (score 0):

The `u8` string prefix is, indeed, C++11, or higher.

However, unless your string literals actually contain non-Latin characters, `U+0x0080` and higher, it makes no difference whatsoever.

Comment: the literal string will not. However if I get the table name from SQLite to be UTF-8 and will push it in non-UTF-8  string, what will be the result?

Comment: @Igor Nothing. It's a dirty little secret is that there is no such thing as a "UTF-8" string or a "non UTF-8" string. A string is a string. A string contains bytes representing characters. UTF-8 is a mechanism for encoding unicode characters as a byte sequence. u8"À" and "\xc3\x80" results in the same string object, one indistinguishable from the other.

Comment: I understand. The problem is that if I have a standard std::string which will be compiled by MSVC and then my table name or table field will be encoded as UTF-8. I will attach this table name in UTF-8 to the std::string query and pass it back to SQLite which expects UTF-8 encoded query string. What happens? Unfortunately I can't test it...

Comment: @Igor of course you can test it. If you expect to have a successful career and earn a living as a computer programmer, you have no choice but to learn how to test your code.

Comment: I do know how to test. It just looks like I need to supply a Unicode character in the SQLite command-line interface and I doubt I can do that without installing an appropriate support for Asian language. And the trouble is - I'd rather to avoid installing something on my dev machine, because I'm still developing.

Answer (score 0):

Visual C 2010 doesn't appear to support those prefixes. You should be able to just include UTF-8 strings in literals though, since they don't violate the rules for null-terminated strings. There may be some weirdness with the string functions, they'll handle UTF-8 strings OK but they'll interpret them as sequences of single bytes rather than UTF-8 characters so comparisons, case conversion and such won't work quite as expected. You'll need a newer version of Visual Studio to completely clear up the issues.

Also, check on the effects of `#pragma execution_character_set("utf-8")`. It's only available in C++ in Visual Studio, so you may have to compile your C source files as C++ to get access to it.

Comment: my project is C++ and the question is tagged as to be C++.

Comment: Then you should be fine with the pragma. As for SQLite, as long as the contents of the string are UTF-8 it won't care that the compiler doesn't understand UTF-8. As long as the string doesn't have any embedded null characters (UTF-8 doesn't) your C/C++ code will be oblivious, to it it's all just bytes.

Comment: the strings are "std::string query1 = "SELECT ... FROM....";"; which I believe does not carry ;\0' symbol at the end. Also, I believe this #pragma is MSVC-only, correct?

Comment: Yes. MSVC only, and possibly specific to Visual Studio 2010 as later editions have support for the standard prefixes. std::string may or may not have a '\0' in it's internal representation depending on how it's implemented, the c_str() method (which you should use if you need a C string form) will yield a null-terminated C string.